# Bank Transfer email template not translated

Tags: magento2, email-translation

We have 3 payment methods in our shop :

> 1. Sofort
> 2. Paypal
> 3. Bank Transfer

Once an order is placed with `Sofort` or `Paypal`, correctly translated Order Confirmation email is sent to customer.

When the `Bank Transfer` method is used, the Order Confirmation email is sent, but not translated.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: can you show screen-shot which thing is not translated in email.

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: Got any solution for this?